# How to add Interceptors optionally in NestJS

Tags: nestjs, interceptor, nestjs-config

I am using `CacheInterceptor` by NestJS for caching requests and responses using Redis. One of the use cases that I have is to toggle caching (disable it completely) based on an environment variable.

I am using `ConfigModule` to read configs from environment variables and using it across the project.

Using `ConfigService`, I can optionally initialize `CacheModule` but the `CacheInterceptor` applied on the routes fails when it can't find a `CacheManager`.

I would like to add `CacheInterceptor` over a controller method only when the a config variable is set. How can I achieve this?

Sample code that I have:

Extended interceptor to ensure namespace prefix:

```js
@Injectable()
export class CacheRequestInterceptor extends CacheInterceptor {

  trackBy(context: ExecutionContext): string | undefined {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const { httpAdapter } = this.httpAdapterHost;

    return `namespace-prefix:${httpAdapter.getRequestUrl(request)}`;
  }
}
```

Added interceptor over a route:

```js
@UseInterceptors(CacheRequestInterceptor)
@Get()
getSomething(@Query() query: SampleQueryParams): Observable<Something[]> {
  return this.service.lookupSomething(query.q);
}
```

Is there a way to optionally add an interceptor (for example, based on a value read from `ConfigService`)?

Comment: You can override [`CacheInterceptor.intercept()`](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/cache/interceptors/cache.interceptor.ts) and call `super.intercept()` depdending on the config value.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, however, I won't be initialising the `CacheModule` and the initialisation of `CacheRequestInteceptor` would fail because of missing `CacheManager` dependency.